# SwiftUI - Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'ValueWidget' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, accessibility

I am new to swift und swiftUI and started playing around with it. I am getting the following error:

`Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'ValueWidget' conform to 'AccessibilityRotorContent'`.
[Screenshot from the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cptFV.png)

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        let data = (1...100).map { "Item \($0)" }

        let columns = [
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))
        ]
        
        let v: Double = -10.0

        ScrollView {
                   LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                       ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                           ValueWidget(name: item, value: v)
                           v = v + 0.5;
                       }
                   }
                   .padding(.horizontal)
               }
               .frame(maxHeight: 300)
    }
}

/*
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}*/
struct ValueWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ValueWidget(name: "Hello", value: 42.0)
    }
}
```

ValueWidget.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ValueWidget: View {
    var name: String
    var value: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(format: "%.1f", value))
                .font(.system(size: 40))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            Text(name)
        }
        .padding()
        .background()
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .fixedSize()
        .frame(width: 120.0, height: 70.0)
        .padding()
        .accessibilityLabel(Text("\(name), Wert: \(value)"))
    }
}

#Preview {
    ValueWidget(name: "Hello", value: 42.0)
}
```

I have tried replacing

```
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

with

```
struct ValueWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ValueWidget(name: "Hello", value: 42.0)
    }
}
```

as some research suggested. But this doesn't help.

I am using macOS Sonoma and Xcode 15.0

What is the best way to fix this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: The line `v = v + 0.5;` does not look right.

Comment: Thank you very much. That line was the problem.

Comment: Describe how you got it working as you wanted and mark it as the answer, no need to mention my pointer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `v = v + 0.5;` as Henrik said in the comments.

Comment: Ok but what is the solution? A useful answer should contain a good explanation and/or code that shows how to solve the issue

Comment: I have just commented out that line: v = v + 0.5;